# Unpredictable Lengths Of Links between Nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In my D3 force layout when I add circles and links dynamically, the length of the link increases to infinity sometimes. After adding some more nodes it automatically gets corrected.

[image]

The code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="d3.min.js"></script>

<script>


  // var in1=prompt("Name");
  // var in2=prompt("Name");

var n= new Array();
var l=new Array();

var n=[];
var l=[];



  function show()
  {


var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);


d3.select("svg").remove();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);






  force
      .nodes(n)
      .links(l)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(l)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(n)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(force.drag);




  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });


  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  });




}




function add()
{
  try{


  var add_name=prompt("name","Name"); 
  var add_group=parseInt(prompt("group","0"));

   n.push({"name":add_name,"group":add_group});

   if(n.length>1)
   {
  var add_source=parseInt(prompt("source","0"));
  var add_target=parseInt(prompt("target","0"));
  var add_value=parseInt(prompt("value","0"));



  l.push({"source":add_source,"target":add_target,"value":add_value});

  console.log(n);
  console.log(l);
  }

  show();
}


catch(e)
{
  console.log(e);
}


}



</script>

<body onload="show();">
<input type="button" onclick="add();" value="dd">
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are adding a node to the layout while the simulation is still ongoing.  I was able to reproduce the problem if I added one node and quickly added another.

One possibility is to stop the layout during your `add()` function, by calling the [force layout's `stop()` method](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#stop).  You would need to declare your `force` variable outside of your `show()` function, in the same way you have declared your lists of nodes `n` and links `l`.

An alternative, and probably better, approach is only to create the force layout once.  At the moment you create one force layout on page load and one additional force layout for each additional node added.  Problems arise when you update the lists of nodes and links when they are still being used by an 'old' force layout running in the background.  If there's only one force layout created, you shouldn't need to stop it: you just need to call its `start()` method to allow it to reinitialise itself once you've modified the data it is running off.

Comment: It is not necessary to call the `.stop()` method. The essential part is to call the `.start()` method, which will do the initial calculations for distances, link strengths, charges etc. needed to internally set up the force layout. You may call `.start()` at any time, even when the layout is still running, which will do a new init and restart the layout. This [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795) shows, how it could be done.

Comment: @altocumulus: in that case it's probably better to not create a new force layout every time a node is added, as the OP's code currently does.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: I even missed that detail of creating a new layout on every add. That further worsens things and is a very problematic approach. Your second alternative is the way to go.